# MS Access: binding toggle button in a continuous form with an aggregate query

Tags: ms-access, aggregate, togglebutton, continuous-forms

I have data where I have multiple orders per creditor with amounts to be paid.

I created a continuous form which groups the orders by creditors names and shows the sum of the total amount to be paid.

I then want to add a toggle button per row which when clicked will mark all the orders for that creditor (that creditor row) as 'true' to be paid. (THIS I AM UNABLE TO DO)

So, my question is:
How do I bind a toggle button to a row when the rows are produced by an aggregate query in a continuous form for MS Access?

I hope someone has a solution for me?

Thanks

Comment: Aggregate queries are not updatable. While you can bind the Toggle button to the (grouped) *Boolean* field, you will need to do a manual update through code when the button is clicked.

Comment: The fact that you call it a _toggle_ button implies that they should also be able to likewise "unclick" it which would set all the orders to 'false', correct?

Comment: I decided to go for the temporary table creation. which worked best as then I could link the toggle button to each line and then just clear that temporary table once complete